# File extension for GraphQL specs

Tags: graphql

I found this documentation https://the-guild.dev/graphql/modules/docs/essentials/type-definitions but I wonder if there can be any other file extensions for graphql specs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any file can have any file extension. The only thing that matters is that whatever you're injecting it into understands what to do with it. [The example you linked to](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/modules/docs/essentials/type-definitions) uses `.graphql` files because the library it's using (`@graphql-tools/load-files`) defaults to parsing the file extensions `['gql', 'graphql', 'graphqls', 'ts', 'js']`, but [it looks like](https://github.com/ardatan/graphql-tools/blob/0c6a63aa0580f2438538fa63bad202934f870bf0/packages/load-files/src/index.ts#L93-L94) you can pass whatever you want in there. The only thing [that apparently matters for that library](https://github.com/ardatan/graphql-tools/blob/0c6a63aa0580f2438538fa63bad202934f870bf0/packages/load-files/src/index.ts#L159-L165) is that if it's not `.js` or `.ts` then it has to be `utf-8` and SDL.